# How to extract RTCP information in a real-time stream using JRTPLIB? C++

Tags: c++, rtsp, rtp, rtcp

By using ***jrtplib***, I've written both server and client side for RTP h264 video streaming and adapted them for the client can use RTSP to have control over the quality of the video that is streamed by the server.

Now I am asked to improve these applications by RTCP to make them adaptive. It's said that ***jrtplib*** handles RTCP packets automatically for it's users can fully focus on streaming, I decided to use it's own RTCP structures. However, altough I've read all documents and examples, even the header files, I couldn't find a solution how to get the data handled that is triggered by ***RTPSession*** class and probably stored in ***RTPRawPacket*** class.

I need help. Thanks in advance.

Note: These are all for education purposes and I am still a beginner(student) so for the most part of the code I've got help by the internet and I don't have fully control over the subject.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: You have the `OnRTCPSenderReport` / `OnRTCPReceiverReport` which you can override in your `RTPSession` implementation. Both contain `RTPSourceData` that have all the data from the reports.